# Header de tabela não repete em nova folha ao imprimir

Tags: html, css

Estou com uma tabela de frequência de uma escola e ao imprimir ela gera duas folhas. Porém, o header da tabela que deveria estar sendo exibido nas duas folhas só aparece na primeira. Como o header possui datas com rotação de 90º tive que fixar o valor da altura. O engraçado é que se eu deixar com até 43px o header se repete mas se ele tiver 1px a mais que isso ele já não se repete. Alguém tem alguma ideia do por que isso poderia estar ocorrendo?

Os valores das datas são passados pelo php vindas do banco de dados.

/* Editado */

CSS: https://pastebin.com/v9YHSdLg

HTML: https://pastebin.com/sZMp8dVD

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sem seu CSS não da para te responder amigo, mas um work-around vc pode colocar no @media print position:fixed no header da tabela

Comment: Obrigado por responder @hugocsl . Realmente. Adicionei os codigos do css e do html (php) no pastbin e disponibilizei os mesmos acima.